# why attribute not working with React-Bootstrap Button?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set `setCustomValidity` for my input but it's not working with React-Bootstrap Button component.  It's works fine with "standard" button. In my app `form` and `Button` are in diffrent components.

[live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weZQQO) try set invalid date and click

```
let { Button } = ReactBootstrap;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  formValidation() {
    let inp = document.getElementById("input");
    inp.setCustomValidity("test");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="myform">
          <input id="input"
            type="datetime-local"
           />

        </form>
        <button form="myform" onClick={this.formValidation}>Click </button>
        <Button form="myform" onClick={this.formValidation}>React-Bootstrap btn</Button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to set `type="submit"` on Bootstrap button

Comment: Your CodePen works just fine. The hardcoded `id` values are a red flag, you should probably be using [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but...

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `form="myform"` on the Bootstrap Button is passed down to the button component as a prop which is not handled by react-bootstrap.

Also the default type for a `button` element is `submit` whereas for the **[Bootstrap Button](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons)** component it is button and hence it doesnt work for you.

You would rather specify `type="submit"` on bootstrap button and make use of `ref` instead of direct DOM handling

Code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.formValidation = this.formValidation.bind(this);
  }
  formValidation (){
    this.input.setCustomValidity("test");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="myform">
          <input ref={ref =>this.input=ref}
            type="datetime-local"
           />

        </form>
        <button form="myform" onClick={this.formValidation}>Click </button>
        <Button type="submit" form="myform" onClick={this.formValidation}>React-Bootstrap btn</Button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJVwqe?editors=1111)**